# Checking the best answer should close the prompt

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

Flow: you upvote an answer, the site shows the pop up that says 'don't forget to mark the answer as accepted', you check the accept box. Problem is the prompt still stays there. I think, as a usability thing, the popup should be closed when you accept the answer.

Comment: This being a more general SE point, I'll migrate to meta.so